# Split a string with hyphens into separate words

Tags: macros

I want to write a macro in which I can split a string with a linking character (like a hyphen) into different words. So, I have something like `\macro{one-two-three}` which I would like to split into three different words. Similarly, `\macro{four-five}` should print `"four five"` (please note the space).

A restriction is that I don't want to load any package to keep the tex-file as small as possible. So I don't want to use `xstring` or `substr` or anything else.

How do I write a macro which returns me the separate words?

I'm new here, so my apologies if I didn't explain my problem clearly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With "return" you mean that writing `\macro{four-five}` LaTeX should *print* "four five"?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: Yes indeed. The space inbetween is mandatory for me.

Comment: If you want to keep your tex-file small loading a suitable package is the way to go. I doubt that a handmade definition can be shorter than `\usepackage{...}`.

Answer (score 10):

This will work without any package; but it would be much easier with `xstring` or `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\splitlist}[1]{\@splitlist#1\@nil}
\def\@splitlist#1\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\@spl@tlist#1-\@nil}%
}
\def\@spl@tlist#1-#2\@nil{%
  #1\space
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\unskip}%
  {\@spl@tlist#2\@nil}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\splitlist{}X

X\splitlist{A}X

X\splitlist{A-B}X

X\splitlist{A-B-C}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Version with `xstring`:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\splitlist}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-}{ }}
```

Version with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\splitlist}{>{\SplitList{-}}m}
 {\ProcessList{#1}{\addaspace}\unskip}
\newcommand{\addaspace}[1]{#1\space}
```

Advanced version with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\splitlist}{ m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { ~ }
  \l_tmpa_tl
 }
 \ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

### Alternative way suggested by Herbert:

```
\newcommand{\splitlist}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-
  \lowercase{\def~}{ }%
  \catcode`-=\active
  \splitlistaux}
\newcommand{\splitlistaux}[1]{%
  #1\endgroup}
```

However this definition disallows `\splitlist` being in the argument to another command.

Comment: if we make `-` active and then `let-\space` maybe another idea

Comment: @Herbert It indeed can be.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this elaborate answer, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

What about something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\macro[1]{\@macro[#1-]}
\def\@macro[#1-#2]{#1%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
  \else%
    \space\@macro[#2]%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\macro{one-two-three}

\macro{four-five}

\macro{six}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution, and easier to understand for me as a newbee. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I fail to understand what the `\if` and `\detokenize` really do. Why not add some TeX comments?