# Adjust column width of a table

Tags: tables

I am working on it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\htext[1]{\texttt{0x\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} & \htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} & \htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} &  &  &  &  \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The empty 4 columns will have something very similar. Now, notice that, an `Overfull \hbox` error occurs.

How can I adjust width of each column so that each `\htext{...}` entry is split in to more than one lines (I don't want to reduce font size)? Something like setting `p{2in}` did not help (as it just created one cell entry overlapping with other).

Comment: Do you any suggestions or requirements for how the string `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` might be split across two lines? Maybe unsurprisingly, TeX does not appear to have a hyphenation rule for this string, so you need to provide such information explicitly. Separately, are you really looking to typeset tables containing strings of `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (or `ffffffffffffff`? Must make for really fascinating reading... :-)

Comment: @Mico Just splitting across two lines is sufficient - no hyphenation needed. For your 2nd query, I need to write hex strings of 17 to 20 characters (not all are equal to `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, of course). I have used `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` just to illustrate the scenario.

Comment: You probably want to use a variation on `tabular{|p{40cm}|...` or `tabularx{|X|...}` with the [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package.

Comment: OK, I'm glad you tolerated my attempt at humor. Even if insertion of a hyphen is not required, you still need to state a decision rule for how and where the string ought to be split. E.g., should there be two equally long substrings, or something else?

Comment: @Andrew - What the OP is encountering is that TeX does not  "know" how and where to split up these rather long hex strings.

Comment: @Mico I just want to get rid of `Overfull \hbox`, that's all. `:D`

Comment: Splitting a 22 character string into two will not work, because seven columns would still be too wide.

Comment: @Mico Latex does not split the contents of the l-field of a tabular environment across more than one line. It's more than just an issue of knowing where to split the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, adapted from a macro I found on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457780/latex-apply-an-operation-to-every-character-in-a-string): I define a `\hyphenatestring` macro, that takes string, converts it to lower case and makes it ‘hyphenatable anywhere’. This macro  can be used inside font-changing commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\def\hyphenatestring#1{\xHyphen@te#1$\unskip}
\def\xHyphen@te{\@ifnextchar${\@gobble}{\sw@p{\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\xHyphen@te}}}
\def\sw@p#1#2{\MakeLowercase{{#2}}#1}%\texttt
\makeatother

\newcommand\htexttt[1]{\texttt{\hyphenatestring{0x#1}}}
\newcommand\htextsf[1]{\textsf{\hyphenatestring{0x#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{7}{X|}}
\hline
\htexttt{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}&  & \textbf{\htextsf{CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC}} &  & \textit{\htexttt{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}}{} &  &  \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79573/split-a-string-with-hyphens-into-separate-words), you can define a command to insert a hyphenation break after each character.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitlist}{>{\SplitList{}}m}
 {\ProcessList{#1}{\addabreak}\unskip}
\newcommand{\addabreak}[1]{#1\-}
```

After that, you can redefine your command to make use of this:

```
\newcommand\htext[1]{\texttt{0x\MakeLowercase{\splitlist{#1}}}}
```

And then play with the column widths until it fits your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitlist}{>{\SplitList{}}m}
 {\ProcessList{#1}{\addabreak}\unskip}
\newcommand{\addabreak}[1]{#1\-}

\newcommand\htext[1]{\texttt{0x\MakeLowercase{\splitlist{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.11\textwidth}|p{0.11\textwidth}|p{0.11\textwidth}|%
p{0.11\textwidth}|p{0.11\textwidth}|p{0.11\textwidth}|p{0.11\textwidth}|}
\hline
\htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} & \htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} &
\htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} & \htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} &
\htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} & \htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} &
\htext{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF} \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MWE]

Comment: `Overfull \hbox` still remains. Anyway, I appreciate your attempt.

Comment: Are you sure it was overfull? I got underfull on this example (probably because of that last 'f'), but like I said, you can fiddle with the column widths. I didn't test it until the error was gone because it will depend on your paper size, font size, etc, so there is no one-size-fits-all solution, I think.

Comment: Why `\-`? You can add `\hspace{0pt}` and no hyphen will show.

Comment: @egreg Perfect. I didn't know that

Comment: @ZéLoff Here goes the error: `line 13: Overfull \hbox (4.65147pt too wide) in paragraph`. Before that, there are 14 `Underfull \hbox`es also.